# Module not found, require('file.hbs')

Tags: webpack, gulp, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars in a project using these posts:

https://n8d.at/blog/how-to-use-handlebars-in-sharepoint-framework-projects-spfx/ https://n8d.at/blog/first-handlebars-web-part-in-spfx/

in my gulp.js file, I have this code to extend Webpack

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
   additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration)=> {
         generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push( 
            { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-template-loader" } ); 
       return generatedConfiguration; 
    }
    }); 
 build.initialize(gulp);
```

I created a new file under config folder, called copy-static.assets.json, with this code inside:

```
{"includeExtensions": ["hbs"]}
```

i have the template on the same level as .ts webpart file, and i reference the template like this:

```
var compiled = require('./test.hbs');
```

am getting this error when I run gulp serve:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test.hbs' using description file: C:\solutions\mywebpart\package.json . Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Note I am using Webpack 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
const loaderRule = {
    "use": [{
    "loader": "handlebars-template-loader"
    }],
    "test": /\.hbs/
};

build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
    generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(loaderRule);

    return generatedConfiguration;}
});
```